# VB Delete Files That Match List

Tags: vb.net

Okay, so I'm creating a small and simple program to manage some files in a given directory. However the program has multiple settings, where it removes certain files depending upon the settings. I have two hurdles that are no doubt easy for more experienced coders... Firstly, **how do I create a list containing file names?** and then how do I compare the files sequentially in the given directory with this list? Ideally I want the code to generate a pre-decided list of file names for multiple lists. For example:

```
List1 -

FileName1.png
FileName2.png

Lst 2 -

FileName3.png
FileName4.png
```

Here's my code so far...

```
Dim Path As String = "C:\SampleFolder\"

    'Check if files match file names in list if so delete

    For Each file In Path
        If fileName = List1 Then
            'delete file
        Else
            'do nothing to that file.
        End If
    Next
```

Basically how do I go about building a list I can easily compare file names to so that I can remove a file if it matches the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to create a list is to use the `List` class. You can then use a `For Each` loop to process each item in the list. You can use `IO.File.Exists` to check if the file exists and then `IO.File.Delete` to delete it.

```
Dim list1 As New List(Of String) From {"FileName1.png", "FileName2.png"}

For Each listFile As String In list1
    Dim filePath As String = IO.Path.Combine("C:\SampleFolder", listFile)
    If IO.File.Exists(filePath) Then IO.File.Delete(filePath)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, your solution proved to be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim List1 As New List(Of String)
Dim List2 As New List(Of String)

Sub Main()

    Dim files() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\SampleFolder")

    List1.Add("FileName1.png")
    List1.Add("FileName2.png")
    List2.Add("FileName3.png")
    List2.Add("FileName4.png")

    ProcessFiles(files, List1)
    ProcessFiles(files, List2)

End Sub

Private Sub ProcessFiles(files() As String, l As IList(Of String))

    For Each f As String In files
        If l.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f)) Then
            'delete file
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```